# Transitioning between div's with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have three `div`s. I have a main div that presents the user an option of choosing to view the two other divs. It works okay if I use just text and do not hide the original div. But I want to use an image map and have the main div hide then if the user chooses they can click a back button and have the div re-appear and the one they are viewing fade out. I have it partly worked out but need help finishing the script so it works properly as JS is not my strong suit. Here is the code:

***JS***

```
// I am using jQuery Version 1.7.2

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

//Script for Choosing which form to display
$j("#transformed-link, #changed-link").live('click',
 function(){  

    //figure out what button was clicked. 
    if(this.id === "transformed-link"){
        var btnA = $j(this);
        var btnB = $j("#changed-link");
        var divA = $j('#transformed-aviation');
        var divB = $j('#changed-aviation');
    }
    else{
        btnA = $j(this);
        btnB = $j("#transformed-link");
        divA = $j('#changed-aviation');
        divB = $j('#transformed-aviation');
    }

    //make sure it is not already active, no use to show/hide when it is already set
    if(btnA.hasClass('active')){
        return; 
    }

    //see if div is visible, if so hide, than show first div
    if(divB.is(":visible")){        
        divB.fadeOut("slow", function(){
             divA.fadeIn("slow");
        });
    }
    else{//if already hidden, just show the first div
        divA.fadeIn("slow"); 

         //Add and remove classes to the buttons to switch state
    btnA.addClass('active').removeClass('inactive ');
    btnB.removeClass('active').addClass('inactive ');

    }
}
```

);

***HTML***

```
<div id="nav-main">
<!-- This is the original main div that users will choose which div to show. -->
<img src="nav-main.jpg" width="940" height="400" usemap="#Map" border="0" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="52,146,420,258" href="#transformed-link" class="inactive" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="536,145,876,267" href="#changed-link" class="inactive"  />
</map>
</div>

<div id="transformed-aviation" class="hide">
<!-- CONTENT OF DIV -->
Link to return to main div? 
</div>

<div id="changed-aviation" class="hide">
<!-- CONTENT OF DIV -->
Link to return to main div? 
</div>
```

***CSS***

> /* Majority of the CSS is only page specific. nav-main, transformed-aviation, changed-aviation are just identifiers for JS and have no code assigned to them. */

```
.hide{ display:none; }
```

My question comes down to this:

How do you fade out the original div and have it fade in the one that the user choose. Then with a link allows an user to go back to the main div (thus fading out the current div and fading in the main or original div).

Feel free to modify or completely rewrite the original script. But please provide examples as [I had help with this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975480/jquery-changing-styles-and-displaying-certain-elements) and do not know enough JS to write it by myself.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the css it's using too, will help in creating a test environment.

Comment: @Jeemusu - 99% of the CSS is just styling for the page. I have edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Also I've made a change to your javascript because it wasn't correct. Find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Fpxyj/

Comment: @AdamMerrifield - I am using 1.7.2 of jQuery. What did you change, can you mark it pointing it out?  Thanks!

Comment: You were missing `);` at the end of the very last line, I also changed the way the first if statement works, but that wasn't critical.

Comment: Can you show us a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you want a `back` control for two `div`s to main `div` and a select div option in main div.

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/rY293/3/)*** is a working Live Demo.

You can use ANYTHING in your `div`s and not just images. I have **completely** changed your JavaScript. Comment if you want any more help.

Comment: Thanks, I notice one issue, the div after it appears does not disappear again. I do not know why that is happening. It is happening with @DaiYoukai 's answer also.

Comment: you may also set a `overflow:hidden` to the child divs.

Comment: Well I am a bit stuck it would seem. The Test Page [(link)](http://www.ubhape2.com/test3.html) doesn't seem to work at all but using a simplified version of the code when I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/Whvdr/) it worked without issue. Can you help spot the problem?

Comment: From inspecting your page, i found a problem. You have to wrap your fade functions inside `$(document).ready( function() {        });` . Let me know if the problem fixed.

Comment: It is always the little things that I seem to forget. Thanks for pointing that out and yes it works great now! Thanks!  Now on the my [next problem...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982412/multiple-galleries-on-same-page-using-featured-box-slider)

Answer (score 2):

Recoded at http://jsfiddle.net/YzNcR/

I changed the `href="#etc.."` into `href="#"` and added `id="etc.."` - More common to use id and classes then hrefs as selectors

Added a back link to the other two divs (Simple link with `class="back"`)

I rewrote the JQuery the be a bit more concise. Simply put if anything matching and id of `transformed-link` or `changed-link` or a class of `back` is clicked it sets off the click handler.

From there it checks to see WHAT got clicked using `e.target.name` (e being an event object) and based on what was clicked it fades out and fades in.

If you're clicking `transformed-link` or `changed-link` it fades out `nav-main` then fades in the appropriate div.

If you're clicked `back` it fades out the current elements parent (the back links parent being the parent div in this case) and then fades in `nav-main`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I seem to have one issue though. When I click the link it shows the gallery. However when I click back it does not hide the original div. I have copied your code exactly and not sure what is going on. When watching the actions in Firebug I can see that `display: none;` is not being added back so it stays `block`. Note: The main-nav does disappear and come back properly, it is only the two other div's that do not.

Comment: Well you already got your proper answer but thought I'd reply anyway. I believe the issue was just because of those other divs needing to by default have display: none; on them. Not sure if you used that part of the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In the  tags, `href="#xxx"` should be `id="xxx"`.